# Update graphicImage after upload

Tags: primefaces

I want to update a graphicImage after a new profile image has been uploaded.

```
<h:panelGroup id="profileImage" layout="block">
                <p:graphicImage id="myImage" cache="false" value="#{myProfile.usersProfileImage}" />    
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myProfile.fileUploadListener}"
                    mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000"
                    update="profileImage"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
                <pe:imageAreaSelect id="imageCropper" for="myImage" hide="false"
                    imageHeight="250" imageWidth="250" aspectRatio="1:1">
                    <p:ajax event="selectEnd"
                        listener="#{myProfile.selectEndListener}" />
                </pe:imageAreaSelect>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

In my backing bean

```
public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) {

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO
                    .read(event.getFile().getInputstream());
            if (image != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputStream);
                user.setProfileJpegImage(outputStream.toByteArray());
            } else {
                throw new IOException("FAILED TO CONVERT PICTURE");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

I dont know why but the image does not update. If I refresh the page with f5 the image is updated.
I also tried to update="myImage" but it work neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussed many times in the PrimeFaces forum.
It's a bug and it's fixed in elite versions and for the upcomfing 5.0

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no fix for this bug, but some Workarounds exists. See also [this Thread.](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34206)
The workarounds in this thread suggest to append a random parameter to the images *src* attribute, either via Javascript or via a backing bean. This forces the browser to reload the image.

If you are using a *fileUpload*, then insert your JS-Code into the *oncomplete* attribute.

Comment: Information for those comming here and using PF 6.1 (community edition): something is still not right with graphicImage control. Workaround suggested by Xecu helps though.

Answer (score 0):

I lost so many times with this problem that I decided to change completely the way I work with it all. 
I use AWS S3 file system to host my images. I upload it there and save info like originalFileName, MimeType, newFileName, bucketName, etc in database. Each file has a database object for it.
I upload it with no problem. After upload the file I force the redirect to update the file:

```
NavigationHandler handler = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
handler.handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "/dashboard?faces-redirect=true");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```

I view the file with:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{userImageFileBean.endereco}"
                                    title="#{userImageFileBean.userImageFile.title}" 
                                    alt="#{userImageFileBean.userImageFile.alt}" 
                                    />
```

The userImageFileBean endereco method returns a String with the file S3 address. The S3 bucket should have a read-only policy. Anyone will be able to download all your files if the address you build use only ids and other common words. For run out this kind of issue you can make the address and the name file based on UUID, that is hard to discover. I hope I could help you with this issue that took me out of bed for 2 weeks.